# Javascript environment sharing between different script tags in browser

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am very new to JavaScript and coming from a c++ background I am finding myself getting a little confused. I have a javascript file setting up a working enviornment factory class for another javascript file like so:

```
<body>
<script src = "environment.js" ></script>
<script src = "main.js" ></script>
</body>
```

The idea is that different index.html will have different environment.js file which configure the environment differently but share the same main.js file.

I also have a simple factory.js file which gets required by both environment.js and main.js (this is what environment.js configures and main.js uses)

Factory.js

```
function PlatformFactory(){
    this._factories = {};
}

PlatformFactory.prototype.registerService = function(name, service) {
    this._factories[name] = service;
}

PlatformFactory.prototype.requestService = function(name) {
    if (name in this._factories) {
        return this._factories[name];
    }
    throw Error("No service called " + name + " found in platform factory");
}

var factory = new PlatformFactory();
module.exports = factory;
```

Environment.js

```
(function () {
    var mod_platform_factory = require("../../../platform/factory.js");
mod_platform_factory.registerService("connection", require("./connection.js"));
})();
```

I have stripped both those two files for ease of reading and ommited including the connection.js code as I believe it is unecessary. Everything works as expected and the connection object sits happily in _factories of the singular PlatformFactory object.

Then it starts executing main.js

```
var mod_platform_factory = require("../../libs/platform/factory.js");

$(document).ready(function () {
    var connection = mod_platform_factory.requestService("connection");
    connection.connect();       
}
)
```

Now I never get to the line connection.connect() because the requestService function throws the error that I places inside PlatformFactory.requestService. Looking into the PlatformFactory._factories object there is no service called connection.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The mod_platform_factory that is created in your environment.js is overwritten by the mod_platform_factory that you create in your main.js.

The latter one does not have a connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I renamed the second one in main.js as mod_platform_factory_test and it made no difference.

Comment: mod_platform_factory_test  would also not have a connection, In your main,js, you would have top refer to the previously created mod_platform_factory (the one created in environment.js). That mod_platform_factory *does* have a connection.